# Select rows under condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, subset

I have two dataframes, one containing observations from what people bought in a grocery store and one containing a list of participants:

`df1 <- data.frame(Person = sample(1:5, size=10, replace = T), Object = sample(letters[1:5], size=10, replace = T))`

`df2 <- data.frame(Participant = c(1, 3, 5))`

Example:

**df1:**

| Person | Object |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | a |
| 1 | c |
| 5 | d |
| 4 | e |
| 1 | b |
| 2 | a |
| 3 | b |
| 2 | c |
| 5 | d |

**df2:**

| Person |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 3 |
| 5 |

I would like to create a subset of df1 containing only the observations where `df1$Person == df2$Participant`

Desired outcome:

**df1.2:**

| Person | Object |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | c |
| 5 | d |
| 1 | b |
| 3 | b |
| 5 | d |

I tried using:
`participant <- df2$Participant df1.2 <- subset(df1, Person == participant)`

And also

`df1.2 <- df1  %>% filter(Person == df2$Participant)`

Since they don't have the same length it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Comment: you should replace `filter(Person == df2$Participant)` by `filter(Person %in% df2$Participant)`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  inner_join(df2,by = c("Person" = "Participant"))
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, I actually have more variables in both dataframes and it adds some variables of the 1st one to the 2nd one and gives me 0 observations

Comment: It should probably have been a `semi_join`.